# Finding row-wise maximum value column with distinct column indices in a numpy matrix

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, performance, numpy

I have a large `numpy` matrix of the order of 10,000 rows and 10,000 columns of `float` type. For each row, I need to find the column index with maximum value and select each column at most once.

For example, for the given array `arr`, I need the output as a `list`/`array` of `(row index, column index)` tuples as given in `out`:

```
arr = np.array(
   [[0.86, 0.23, 0.83, 0.79],
   [0.15, 0.98, 0.86, 0.47],
   [1.  , 0.08, 0.01, 0.04],
   [0.78, 0.82, 0.17, 0.56],
   [0.73, 0.91, 0.52, 0.31]])
out = [(0,0),(1,1),(2,3),(3,2)]
```

Explanation:

- Initially `out` is empty.
- For `row 0`, the maximum value is `0.86` in `column 0`, so `out` is now `[(0,0)]`
- For `row 1`, the maximum value is `0.98` in `column 1`, and `column 1` isn't already present in out, so `out` is now `[(0,0),(1,1)]`
- For `row 2`, the maximum value is `1` in `column 0`, but `column 0` has already been selected, so we look for next maximum, i.e. `0.08` in `column 1`, which is also present in `out`, then next maximum, i.e. `0.04` in `column 3`, so `out` is now `[(0,0),(1,1),(2,3)]`
- Similarly, for `row 3`, the column with maximum value that hasn't been already selected is `column 2`, so final `out` is `[(0,0),(1,1),(2,3),(3,2)]`

I want to compute it as efficiently as possible. The `O(n`<sup>2</sup>`)` solution using 2 `for` loops is trivial, so any solution better than this (either better time complexity or better runtime using inbuilt `numpy` functions) would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the minimum value in the matrix is 0

```
for i in range(len(arr)): # for the ith row
    maxcol = np.argmax(arr[i])
    arr[:,maxcol] = np.zeros( len(arr[:,maxcol]) )
    out.append((i,maxcol))
```

This works by finding the index of the max column for a row (using `argmax`), and then setting all of that column's elements to an arbitrary minimum value (`0` here, given efficiently by `np.zeros`)

This should work, I'm trying it out rn. And is definitely less than `O(n^2)` but don't know exactly how much.

Edit: I tried it and `out` is `[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 3), (3, 2), (4, 0)]`. So it does have the desired output, but an extra term (4,0). [which is there because iterates over all rows].
If you want to iterate till you 'run out' of columns, you can use `min(arr.shape)` instead of `len(arr)`

---

##### Time Complexity

We're running a `for` loop once, that takes `O(n)`
Inside the for loop, we have `np.argmax`, which is also `O(n)`
Then comes the replacements which are constant time [`O(1)`]

So it's not that optimised. You can write your own code for that, by directly coding the edge cases and other improvements like checking only the required parts, etc...

Comment: Funny I just wrote almost the exact same code. But I think you should replace `np.zeros( len(arr[:,maxcol]) )`  by `-np.inf`. That's faster and cleaner.

Comment: yes, especially if the actual matrix can have negative values as well.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. A runtime comparison on large array (10000x10000) with the benchmark of 2 for loops would also be appreciated. Although it is O(n^2), it might have a better runtime because of numpy functions.

Comment: @Kapil I tried to run it with 10^5 by 10^5 random numbers and ran out of memory :)

Comment: Maybe 10^4 by 10^4 then

Comment: @Kapil For 10^4 by 10^5 it takes 17.6s with the -np.inf replacement and 38.8 without it.

Answer (score 2):

If you're open to using cython, the iteration can be sped up somewhat.

```
# distutils: language = c++
# cython: boundscheck = False

from libcpp.set cimport set as cset
from libc.math cimport INFINITY

def method2(double[:, :] x):
    cdef:
        int nrows, ncols, i, j, best_j
        double best_value
        # Define the set of columns that have already been used.
        cset[int] usedcols
        
    nrows = x.shape[0]
    ncols = x.shape[1]
    out = []
    
    for i in range(nrows):
        best_value = -INFINITY
        best_idx = -1
        
        # Find the largest value for each row that's not already used.
        for j in range(ncols):
            if x[i, j] > best_value and usedcols.find(j) == usedcols.end():
                best_value = x[i, j]
                best_j = j
        out.append((i, best_j))
        usedcols.insert(best_j)
    
    return out
```

Assuming Samarth's solution is `method1`, here's a performance comparison.

```
x = np.random.normal(0, 1, (10000, 10000))
%timeit method1(x)  # 770 ms ± 4.98 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit method2(x)  # 57.7 ms ± 149 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```